# Find Eloquent Class by Table Name

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm currently wrapping Laravel/Eloquent around a legacy database and building up relations, however I'm running into an issue with some of the existing system's dynamic nature. Some relations are defined within the database, itself, meaning items in `table_a` could relate to any number of other tables depending on stored instructions.

This includes table names being stored within the instructions.

My current objective is to find the Eloquent `Model` class that's been built for table X.

Some notes:

- For backwards compatibility I can't change the existing database entries to store classes instead of table names.
- Because our table names don't adhere to Laravel's naming conventions I can't assume class names based on table names.
- The database has over 300 tables and over 100 currently used in mapping instructions, so I'd prefer a dynamic solution not requiring extensive class<->table mapping lists when Eloquent models already maintain that in the `$table` property.

Maybe I'm just hoping Laravel keeps a manifest of all Eloquent classes somewhere in memory that I could leverage but that's probably wishful thinking.

Any clever ideas?

Comment: Your question is far too broad to be answered. Are you saying you want to use a table name instead of a class name to identify a polymorphic relationship?

Comment: The driver for this is to build polymorphic relationships but the question is more general: I have table names and I need to figure out what Model classes have been built for them. And I'm hoping for a solution that can leverage the fact the classes already have the `$table` property with the necessary information.

Comment: You're hoping for a solution, but you haven't clearly articulated what the problem is. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types

Comment: The problem is that I have a list of table names and I need to identify which Eloquent models have been built for them, and I'm looking for a dynamic way to achieve that without relying on explicit mapping tables that might be poorly maintained. That's the problem, as I've stated a couple times simply and succinctly now. What I'm intending to do with the classes is ultimately outside the scope of the stated problem.

Comment: I'd suggest you start with PHP's `Reflection` classes. You should be able to get the value of the `$table` property for each of your model classes. https://www.php.net/reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into Reflection, per miken32's advice, I was able to compile snippets of samples and add functionality to a BaseModel class. This might not be my final implementation but it got me what I needed.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

abstract class BaseModel extends Model
{
    public static function tableName(): string
    {
        return with(new static)->getTable();
    }

    public static function getClassMetadata(): Collection
    {
        return Cache::rememberForever('model:eloquent:metadata',function(){
            return collect(File::allFiles(app_path()))->map(function ($item){
                $path = $item->getRelativePathName();
                return sprintf('\%s%s', Container::getInstance()->getNamespace(),
                    strtr(substr($path, 0, strrpos($path, '.')), '/', '\\'));
            })->filter(function ($class){
                $valid = false;
                if (class_exists($class)) {
                    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($class);
                    $valid = $reflection->isSubclassOf(BaseModel::class) && !$reflection->isAbstract();
                }
                return $valid;
            })->map(function ($class){
                $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($class);
                return [
                    'fqcn' => $class,
                    'table' => $reflection->getMethod('tableName')->invoke(null)
                ];
            })->values();
        });
    }
}
```